# Get index of array starting from last element

Tags: python

How is that i get the reverse iteration using the following code. Should I be using the reduce function or something?

Example:

```
for i in range(4):
    print i ////0 1 2 3
```

how do i print the same in the reverse order

```
3 2 1 0

a=[5,2,1,4,3]
```

I also want to print the above array in reverse using the index and not `a[::-1]`
i.e,i want to first print

```
 a[4] //get index starting from last how to achieve this
 a[3]
 a[2]
 a[1]
 a[0]
```

Comment: `range(4, 0, -1)` creates a reverse range. Don't understand second part of your quetion, though.

Comment: @kirilloid `range(4, 0, -1)` is not `reversed(range(4))`

Comment: Yes, it should be `range(3, -1, -1)` and solution with `reversed` is better

Comment: For the last part of your question, maybe `for i, x in reversed(list(enumerate(a)))` will suit better than `for i in range(len(a), -1, -1)`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [**reversed**](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#reversed) function:

```
for i in reversed(range(4)):
    print i
```

prints:

```
3
2
1
0
```

and

```
a=[5,2,1,4,3]
for i in reversed(a):
    print i
```

prints

```
3
4
1
2
5
```

Answer (score 1):

One approach involves reversing a list before iterating over it. Though this technique wastes computer cycles, memory, and lines of code:

```
rseqn = list(seqn)
rseqn.reverse()
for value in rseqn:
    print value
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the reverse function of a list.

```
>>> a = [1,2,3,4]
>>> a.reverse()
>>> a
[4, 3, 2, 1]
```

Use the answer of eumiro for a one time reverse (i.e. if you only need it once).
Otherwise use my approach because the conversion is done on the list itself.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
range(4, -1, -1)
// [4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> for i in reversed(range(4)):
...   print(i)
...
3
2
1
0
```

Answer (score 0):

`len()` returns the length of a list. So you can use `len(a)-1` to get the last index of list `a` .